# Unable to get an element attribute while parsing xml using Jquery

Tags: jquery

I need to parse the  below xml element , fetch the attribute image of that element

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<categories1>
   <Snacks name="Samosa" />
   <Snacks name="Chips" />
   <Samosa name="Big" image="bigsamosa.jpg" desc="big" />
   <Samosa name="small" image="samosa.jpg" desc="small " />
   <Bottle1 name="1Litre" image="pepsibottle70ml.jpg" desc="Samosa Bottle1" />
   <Bottle1 name="40Litres" image="thumspuptin.jpg" desc="ThumpsUp Samosa" />
   <Chips name="UncleChips" />
   <UncleChips name="Uncle Chip" image="unclechips.jpg" desc="UncleChips" />
   <Pet1 name="50ml" image="thumspuppet.jpg" desc="50ml Thumps Up Pet1" />
   <HotChips name="Hot Chip" image="HotChips.jpg" desc="HotChips" />
   <Chips name="HotChips" />
</categories1>
```

I need to parse the  above xml element , fetch the attribute image of that element

I tried using jquery this way

If elemnt UncleChips is given , i am trying to fetch this way

```
 var names = $(xmldoc).find('UncleChips').attr("image").text();
```

But its giving undefined

Comment: have you check length of UncleChips ?

Comment: remove `.text()` as you're retrieving an attribute which HAS to be text anyway. [Here's your working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h2er2/)

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
$(xmldoc).find('UncleChips').attr('image');
```

Answer (score -1):

Use only

`$(xmldoc).find('UncleChips').attr("image");`

this will gives you value of it.